# MongoDB Error: Unable to reach primary for set [set_name] when connect to mongo replica set

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, replicaset

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB replica set consists of 3 mongo docker-container, but Error Message: `Unable to reach primary for set rs0` occurs.

Git Repository: https://github.com/frontalnh/mongodb-replica-set

I made docker swarm consists of 3 MongoDB docker-container and map each port to localhost: 27017, 27018, 27019

Connecting to a single mongo docker-container is possible by below command

```
mongo localhost:27017
```

**But** When I try to connect to Replica set consists of 3 by below command,

Error Message: `Unable to reach primary for set rs0` occurs

**Command**

```
mongo "mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/testdb?replicaSet=rs0"
```

**Configuration**

```
cfg = {
  _id: 'rs0',
  members: [
    { _id: 0, host: 'mongo-rs0-1:27017' },
    { _id: 1, host: 'mongo-rs0-2:27017' },
    { _id: 2, host: 'mongo-rs0-3:27017' }
  ]
};
cfg.protocolVersion = 1;
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo-rs0-1:
    image: 'mongo-start'
    build: ./mongo-rs0-1
    ports:
      - '27017:27017' # left is computer's port right side is docker internal port
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-1/data:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo-rs0-2'
      - 'mongo-rs0-3'

  mongo-rs0-2:
    image: 'mongo'
    command: --replSet rs0
    command: --config ./conf/mongo.conf
    ports:
      - '27018:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-2/data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-rs0-2/conf:/conf

  mongo-rs0-3:
    image: 'mongo'
    command: --replSet rs0
    command: --config ./conf/mongo.conf
    ports:
      - '27019:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-3/data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-rs0-2/conf:/conf

  setup-rs:
    image: 'setup-rs'
    build: ./setup
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo-rs0-1' # mongo-rs0-1 서비스가 실행중이어야 해당 서비스가 실행될 수 있다.

  adminmongo:
    image: 'mrvautin/adminmongo'
    ports:
      - '1234:1234'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by register host name in localhost

Anyone who needs mongo replica set in localhost can setup replica set with docker-compose.

https://github.com/frontalnh/mongodb-replica-set

Answer (score 0):

You were maybe running the other node of the replica set in fork mode and you turned off your computer at some point. Restarting those nodes in fork mode by doing `mongod --config [your_config_file.conf] --fork` fixed the problem for me.

What happens when all other secondary nodes are unreachable is that the primary node becomes secondary therefore you will be unable to elect a new primary.

Try to restart the other nodes using their configuration files and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the current primary node.
Repeat this until the desired node become primary. After that, you are able to run mongos.

Note: Make sure that there isn't traffic to the database.